# Undefined control sequence : maketitle() in overleaf , EMNLP 2020

Tags: titles

I am getting "Undefined control sequence error in OVERLEAF while using EMNLP-2020 template. It works fine and produces the required output, but I cant upload to arxiv due to the error. Any suggestions please...

the code is:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[hyperref]{emnlp2020}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\renewcommand{\UrlFont}{\ttfamily\small}

\aclfinalcopy % Uncomment this line for the final submission
%\def\aclpaperid{***} %  Enter the acl Paper ID here

\title{This is the title  for EMNLP-2020}

\author{{ABC, PQR \and XYZ}\\
\institute{Department of 1234, University of 1234}\\
\email{\{ abc.abc, pqr.pqr, xyz.xyz\}@1234.xx.xx}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

This is the test document
```

And it shows the following error

[image]

Answer (score 3):

remove the undefined `\institute` and `\email` macros from your title:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[hyperref]{emnlp2020}
%\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\renewcommand{\UrlFont}{\ttfamily\small}

\aclfinalcopy % Uncomment this line for the final submission
%\def\aclpaperid{***} %  Enter the acl Paper ID here

\title{This is the title  for EMNLP-2020}

\author{ABC, PQR \and XYZ\\
Department of 1234, University of 1234\\
\{abc.abc, pqr.pqr, xyz.xyz\}@1234.xx.xx
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

This is the test document


\end{document}
```

[image]